# Trying to post a chatter feed item with mention and as someone else

Tags: apex, chatter-feed

I'm only able to either post as someone else or include a mention. I have not been able to do both.

Here's the code where I'm able to post as someone else:

```
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = '0F9c0000000DLT6CAO'; 
post.createdById = '005a000000BA2zjAAD';
post.Body = 'Happy Anniversary, Sean!';
insert post;
```

Here's the code where I'm able to post with a mention:

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
textSegmentInput.text = 'Congratulate ';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

mentionSegmentInput.id = '005a0000009bsmSAAQ';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

textSegmentInput.text = ' on his ' + numberOfYears + '-year anniversary!';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);     

feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
feedItemInput.subjectId = '0F9c0000000DLT6CAO'
ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null, feedItemInput, null);
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message you are getting please?

Comment: There is no error message. Both methods work, but using the first, I can post as someone else without being able to mention (there is not method that allows me to using FeedItem) and the second allows me to post a mention, but I can't post as someone else using FeedElement. My requirement is to be able to post as someone else and also mention another user in the body.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't post as someone else using ConnectAPI - it always uses the current user context. But you can now use Process Builder to do @mentions, so you could maybe write a workflow rule that would post as running user?

Comment: Thanks @BritishBoyinDC. Can I post on behalf of any user?

Comment: Not that I know of unless something has recently changed, but when I asked about it at DF it wasn't considered a priority...I think the user context is too baked into Chatter to make that possible. One way I have got round it is to use an Apex Email Service since that runs in the context you setup for the service - so you could hand off to an email service and have that post for you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the ConnectApi classes currently don't support posting as another user. See here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_differences.htm

In order to do that you have be login as another user

Sample code.

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

mentionSegmentInput.id = Userinfo.getUserId();
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

textSegmentInput.text = 'Could you take a look?';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
feedItemInput.subjectId = '0019000001cFlDS';

ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItemInput, null);
```

Pass userid `mentionSegmentInput.id = userId` and `feedItemInput.subjectId` recordId

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above example still shows that you are posting the feed update: "ratan paul to linspire Only". I would like it to be posted on behalf or another user.

Comment: In order to do that you have be login as  another user

Comment: I'm running this through a batch class and it will only post as the author, I believe.

Comment: I just read up on System.runAs() and it seems that it is only used for test methods: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm

Answer (score 1):

What is you use case for wanting to be able to post a mention from someone other than the context user?

I ask this because it is true that you need to use feedelement to make a post with a mention and this method does not yet support posting from anyone other than the context user. However if you only want he mentions to be from say a system admin context then there is an ugly but quit workable way around this limitation.

Step one set up a helper object to collect the mention id, subject id and message text.

Step two create your class to make the post using the fields that will be from your helper object. ( include a sent flag )

Step three set up a schedulable batch class  this will query all the unsent messages in the helper object, pass them to the posting class and set the sent flag to true  say every 10 minutes. The context user for the schedulable class is the user that initiated it. (like a sys admin account).

Thus you get your at mentions that use this route all from the one user.

Its ugly, and will only be useful in a handful of scenarios but it does work. I my case it is used to fake push notifications to the SF1 mobile app. If you are mentioned in a post then you can get a push notification. This technique allows for any event to add a mention record in the helper object and therefore a post with a mention and thus a push notification.

Yes its an elaborate workaround that might never see the light of production but in the sandbox it works.